# How to use "locals()" binding with exec in Python 3.x?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I cannot manage to create a local variable with exec(). I tried `exec(instruction)`, `exec(instruction, locals())` and it didn't work. Only `exec(instruction, globals())` worked, but the variable was created at the global level, which is not what I wanted. here is a piece of code that illustrates my question

```
# remove all variables previously stored in the environment
for name in dir():
    if not name.startswith('_'):
        del globals()[name]

def f1():
    instruction = 'bar=1'
    # exec(instruction) # NameError: name 'bar' is not defined
    # exec(instruction, locals()) # NameError: name 'bar' is not defined
    exec(instruction, globals()) # okish, but not the way I want cause bar is built at the globa scope
    print('bar={} from inside f1'.format(bar))


print('test for global variable')
instruction = 'foo=1'
exec(instruction)
print('foo={}'.format(foo))

print('test for local variable')
f1()

print('bar={} from the outside'.format(bar)) # should raise NameError here but it doesn't
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42911790/2864740

Comment: The post my question is said to be a duplicate is very long and well above my skills. What I understood so far is: 'You can't create new local variables with exec on Python 3'. Is this the final answer to my question?